# how to query strings with - in the text in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I'm looking for data in two fields with one filed must be the same, one using query

```
{
      "from": 0,
      "size": 5,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match":  { "NIPNAS": "2000259"}
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "SID",
                  "query":  "300106840-0031375024"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

when I enter the same text as the one recorded, the data I want appears, but when I only write the text to the dash, the data doesn't appear

Comment: Please share your index mapping and the query you're sending.

Comment: here https://pastebin.com/pwBndWsj

Comment: For exact matches, you should use the `.keyword` field. Can you try?

Comment: can you give me example for that ?

Comment: Use `SID.keyword` instead of `SID` in your query

Comment: solved, i use wildcard not query string

Comment: thanks @Val , for .keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match":  { "NIPNAS": "2000259"}},
        { "wildcard": {
        "SID.keyword": "300106840-00313750*"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

i use wildcard for search not query string